# How to use winston error handling with express-async-errors using ES6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, winston

I'm using ES6 in Node.js and want to handle uncaughtException and unhandledRejection using express-async-errors.
Documentation say that I should only require module, but what should I do with ES6?

```
// require('express-async-errors');

import expressAsyncErrors from 'express-async-errors';
```

Actually I want to handle errors using winston and with **express-async-errors** I want to handle uncought and unhandled errors.
So how can I use it?

Comment: Consider updating the question to be more specific. What you're asking about is ES module `import` syntax, not ES6 syntax in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`express-async-errors` patches `express` package when it's imported.

In case it's imported like

```
import expressAsyncErrors from 'express-async-errors';
```

and `expressAsyncErrors` isn't used, unused import can be dropped, depending on ES module implementation. In order to just import the package, it should be:

```
import 'express-async-errors';
```